# Why does LSTM produce NaN losses?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm implementing my LSTM model for sarcasm detection (binary). I wrote the following code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim,
          weights=[embed_matrix], input_length=max_tweet_len, trainable=False))
model.add(LSTM(lstm_out1, Dropout(0.2), Dropout(0.2)))
#model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
  
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=opt,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My model predicts NaNs.

```
[[nan nan]
 [nan nan]
 [nan nan]
 ...
 [nan nan]
 [nan nan]
 [nan nan]]
```

Why is it happening? My input dimension is (75830, 79). I've checked for missing values/nans. No such anomaly in data. I used this code. In all cases code returned false.

```
check_nan = df['is_sarcastic'].isnull().values.any()
print(check_nan)
check_na = df['is_sarcastic'].isna().values.any()
print(check_na)
check_nan_ = df['tweet_text'].isnull().values.any()
print(check_nan_)
check_na_ = df['tweet_text'].isna().values.any()
print(check_na_)
```

**Edit**

1. Used grad clipping
2. smaller learning rate

Still NaN loss.

Comment: It is either the learning rate is too high or too low. Try tuning `Adam(learning_rate=0.001)` a bit. If the new change does not produce nan loss, then it is the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
model.add(LSTM(lstm_out1, Dropout(0.2), Dropout(0.2)))
```

this Dropout layers do not look correct. I think you should use dropout=0.2,
recurrent_dropout=0.2. Refer the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM.

Also, your embedding initialisation could contain nan values in weights=[embed_matrix]

Comment: Modifying dropout worked. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

But why are you using binary_crossentropy? You have 2 output neurons. It's strange that you have sigmoid activation with 2 output neurons.
In this case you have 2 options:

1. You can use sparse_categorical_crossentropy (or categorical_crossentropy depending if you have one_hot) with 2 output neurons and with softmax activation.
2. You can use binary_crossentropy with only 1 output neuron and with sigmoid activation.

I guess that was the mistake.

Edit:
I am going to give you a working example based on your code so you can compare.

```
x_train = np.random.randint(0, 100, (1000, 10))
y_train = np.random.randint(0, 2, (1000,))

vocab_size = 100
embed_dim = 10
max_tweet_len = 10

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim, input_length=max_tweet_len, trainable=False))
model.add(layers.LSTM(10, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
#model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))

model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
  
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=opt,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Comment: I've changed the dense layer according to your advice. Shared the modified code here. Still NaN but accuracy is not 0.